# How would you know the difference between a compressor stall and a surge based on indications in the cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-performance, jet-engine, engine

I understand the difference between a compressor stall and surge.

Stall: One or two blade stages exceed the critical AoA, the airflow is turbulent, and the smooth airflow through the compressor is disrupted

Surge: Occurs after a compressor stall where most or all the blade stages are affected from it, there’s a complete disruption of airflow through the compressor and restricts airflow to the engine.

A stall produces a big bang, flames at the back and sometimes in front of the engine due to flow inversion, and severe vibrations and engine damage in a severe stall. In the cockpit we can see fluctuations in RPM and raise in EGT.

But what noises/indications a pilot from the cockpit would hear/see in a compressor surge? Are they similar?

Answer (score 4):

Stall and surge are two different, although related, physical phenomena.

> Stall: One or **more** blade stages exceed the critical AoA, the airflow is turbulent, and the smooth airflow through the compressor is disrupted

Correct.

After a stall initiates, the airflow is disrupted. In an axial compressor, a stalled stage causes increased AoA on neighbouring blades, which in turn may enter a stall. The original blades *may*, at this point, exit the stall due to the decreased airflow, hence we have a rotating stall, or the stall can spread to the whole inlet section.

If the stall affects a large part of the compressor stage, the airflow from inlet to outlet cannot be guaranteed, so the (higher) pressure downstream of the stage causes a **backflow**, and

> big bang, flames at the back and sometimes in front of the engine due to flow inversion, and severe vibrations and engine damage

This **inversion** is called surge.

In the end, it is **surge** that you experience in the way you describe, and it is a consequence of a severely stalled compressor. For brevity sake, people say "the compressor stalled" instead of "stalled and now entered surge".